# magento 2 "Header already sent " issue when there is large data in array and json_encode function using in ajax controller

Tags: magento2, controllers

I am developing functionality in `Magento 2.3` version and calling controller function by using Ajax.

Controller function return product data and everything is working fine when **customer is not login.**

While when we try to login and return product data then it throw the error

```
"Exception: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at app/code/Magento2/CustomProduct/Controller/Index/Index.php:74) in vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 148 in vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61"
```

Below is the array and json_encode

```
public function execute() {

    foreach ($collection as $singleProduct):

        $imageUrl = $imageUrl;
        $html.='<div class="col-lg-3">';
        $html.='<p class="img_small"><a href="'.$singleProduct->getProductUrl().'"><img class="custom-category-imgs" src="' . $imageUrl . '" title="' . $singleProduct->getName() . '"></a></p>';
        $html.='<p class="cat_product"><a href="'.$singleProduct->getProductUrl().'">' . $singleProduct->getName() . '</a></p>';
        $html.='<p><a class="btn_blue" href="'.$singleProduct->getProductUrl().'" title="View">View</a></p>';
        $html.='</div>';


    endforeach;
    echo json_encode(array('html_data' => $html,'page_index' => $page));
}
```

and Ajax function is:

```
function load_product(category_id, page, current_obj) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: controller_url,
                        async: true,
                        data: {cat_id: category_id, p: page},
                        success: function (data) {
                            //alert(data);
                            var result = JSON.parse(data);
                            $("#insert_div" + category_id).html(result.html_data);
                            if (current_obj != 'default_val') {
                                setActivePageing(current_obj);
                            } else {
                                setActivePageing('default_val');
                            }
                            $("#wait").hide();

                        }
                    })
                }, 2000);
            }
```

Please help anybody this is the strange issue.

Comment: Hi akgola, I think it would be better if you could share more of your code. We need to know what you are including in html y count variables, the logic behind it to see if we can find out what's producing the issue.

Comment: @PauGNU,question updated with the code.Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` you need to return an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface`.

I'm going to assume line 74 in your error is this `echo json_encode(array('html_data' => $html,'page_index' => $page));`

Try doing the following instead of echoing `json_encode`:

```php
$resultJSON = $this->resultFactory
    ->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
    ->setData(['html_data' => $html,'page_index' => $page]);
return $resultJSON
```

Note: If you get a console error "Unexpected token at line 0 in...", then try removing the `JSON.parse(data)` from your JS file and just use data as is, since `jQuery.ajax` will automatically determine the data-type based on MIME type of the response if you don't explicitly define `dataType`.